# How to see (in view) inserted order

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Im using a html table to show the data.

I have this db

```
id - content - date
1  - text1    - 2017/01/01 7:00
2  - text2    - 2017/01/01 7:01
3  - text3    - 2017/01/01 7:02
```

Example: If i add dynamically a new row in html table between 1 and 2 (new text). I need (SQL QUERY) to see the data in the exact position was inserted.

How can i make this query?

Comment: You're going to have to have an ordering column or something like that. Ordering would just be an integer, and the entire order would change when someone inserted something to the middle of the list.

Comment: Any ideas my friend?

Comment: Usually database tables have a `createdAt` or `updatedAt` column, which you can use in an `ORDER BY` clause. If not, then perhaps the primary key is a autoincrement integer, which can be used and will mostly be ok

Comment: OK. But tell how can I do it

Comment: any solutions??

Comment: updated post,please check